# Java annotations - Identifier or TypeName

Tags: java, annotations, language-lawyer

The Java Language Specification states that [a *normal annotation*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.7.1) is in the format

> *NormalAnnotation*:
>     @ *TypeName* ( *ElementValuePairs*<sub>opt</sub> )

[A single-element annotation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.7.3) is in the format:

> *SingleElementAnnotation:*
>     @ *Identifier* ( *ElementValue* )

I do not understand, why this inconsistency, why is a normal annotation a `TypeName` and a single element annotation an `Identifier`? I believe the reference to `Identifier` might be a mistake in the specification since Identifier is not qualified and javac accepts AnnotationDeclarations that are qualified, for both normal annotations and single element annotations.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reference to `Identifier` is a mistake in the specification since an identifier cannot be  qualified (you can write `@java.lang.SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` but `java.lang.SuppressWarnings` is not a legal identifier). Javac accepts AnnotationDeclarations that are qualified, for both normal annotations and single element annotations. The mistake appears to be recently introduced; older versions of the JLS do not have this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a mistake in the grammar documentation. The single annotation-element and the  marker annotations are **shorthand** for the normal annotation.

You can also see the Java 1.5/1.6 specification: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/interfaces.html#9.7

The single-element annotation is indicated as:

```
SingleElementAnnotation:
    @ TypeName ( ElementValue )
```

Answer (score 0):

The [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.7.1) is stating that Identifiers and TypeNames are two different things. From a programming perspective they are not. But from a logical perspective they could be, with the right analogy.

Starting with [TypeName](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.7.1): Data types (Not counting primitive) and classes usually have more than one methods and/or attributes. So in a way, [TypeName](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.7.1) is kind of like the name of a class or a data type, which it kind of is.

On to [Identifier](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.7.3): An Identifier is used to name or describe ONE variable or ONE class. In the right context, an Identifier can be associated with a single thing, like a int value, while a TypeName can represent an int and a String in one class.

```
int Identifier = 90; //Identifier represents an int value
class TypeName{
int i;
String s;
} //TypeName represents an int value and a String
TypeName MyNew = new TypeName(); //MyNew references to a TypeName, holding more
//than one value
```

This is very discreet logic, so if the logic does not make sense to you at first glance, the author may have changed the names for clarity, to make them a bit different. But no matter what the author calls them, they are the same thing, just worded differently.

Answer (score 0):

It's a matter of semantics (and fairly pedantic semantics at that).

Consider a `NormalAnnotation`, such as `@SuppressWarnings(value={"foo","bar"))`, where the `SuppressWarnings` (the TypeName) resolves to an annotation class that has a member named `value`.

Now consider a `SingleElementAnnotation`, such as `@SuppressWarnings({"foo","bar"))`. The Identifier (`SuppressWarnings`) *is* the name of an interface, but there is nothing that says the one parameter should be assigned to `value`.

So, you cannot directly parse that sequence of characters as a `NormalAnnotation`; it doesn't have a correctly formatted `ElementValuePairs`.  However, if you insert `value=`, between the opening parenthesis and the start of the parameter, then you get something that is parseable as a NormalAnnotation.

Likewise for MarkerAnnotation. It is missing the parenthesis required by the NormalAnnotation.

The Identifier needs to be a value that when used in the NormalAnnotation will yield a TypeName.

The NormalAnnotation has a number of restrictions on it, such as:

> It is a compile-time error if TypeName does not name an annotation type that is accessible (§6.6) at the point where the annotation is used.

Until the SingleElementAnnotation or MarkerAnnotation is transformed into a NormalAnnotation, `SuppressWarnings` is just an Identifier and only needs to conform to the definition of [Identifier](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.8). Note that TypeNames can be qualified, such as `java.lang.SuppressWarnings`, but Identifiers cannot.

I believe the intent was that MarkerAnnotation and SingleElementAnnotation should use simple names (Identifiers) rather than fully qualified names (TypeNames). So *technically* speaking `@Override` is ok, `@java.lang.Override` is incorrect, but `@java.lang.Override()` would be allowed. Every compiler I can get my hands on allows the latter. That makes the distinction rather moot for nearly everyone.